# SSRS - Programmatically import built Reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services, bids

Are there any known good practices on how to import Reports into Reporting Services, without using it's built-in GUI?

I'm in a situation where a project need to upload and update reports to a report server easily, but also be able to easily switch between test and production environment when deploying reports.

Some advice here?

Can I use SSIS integration packets for deploy?

I understand there is a Report WebService. It is usable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting Services offers the **rs.exe** tool for this sort of thing.

See [rs Utility (rs.exe) (SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx).

This utility takes a VB.NET script which contains code that interacts with a specified SSRS web service.

You can add user-defined parameters to specify any other required variable.

The main advantage with this is that **rs.exe** already has all the required references built in, so all you need to is specify the deployment location instead of creating a .NET project with WSDL references, etc.

Disadvantage is that obviously this needs to be installed where you're deploying, i.e. typically run on a server with SSRS already installed. Also, it's VB.NET, which might not be to your taste. But the core functionality, i.e. connection to the web service, basic file operations are all natively available.

You can also use these same sort of web service calls with Powershell.

See [Deploying SSRS artefacts using Powershell ( Simply)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dave_ballantynes_blog/2013/02/12/deploying-ssrs-artefacts-using-powershell-simply/).

This is another lightweight option, depends on how much you like working with Powershell, but all functionality, i.e. file manipulation and web service interaction can be achieved.

I would look at **rs.exe** in the first instance.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the web service, at first it might seem a little difficult.

Use [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7346729b-b19c-453c-a1c1-a0073ef8b69c/using-rsexe-to-deliver-reports-does-not-connect-to-my-shared-datasource?forum=sqlreportingservices) to get started.

There are many more such solutions based on the rs.exe utility that will let you publish reports on a server.

Comment: Thank's. I've seen this very link before. While this Is a approach and the page is not very comprehensive, i'm interested to find out if this approach is one of the better..

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: @GarryEnglish the link was what I used as a reference when posting the answer, will try and update the answer and notify you.

Comment: Is this the updated link? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7346729b-b19c-453c-a1c1-a0073ef8b69c/using-rsexe-to-deliver-reports-does-not-connect-to-my-shared-datasource?forum=sqlreportingservices